# javascript animation work in html page but same script wont work in .net page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, .net

I have this JavaScript for a transforming animation using css transform and waypoint

```
  $('.scrollimation').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).addClass('in');
    },{offset:'80%'});


    $('.projects-container.scrollimation').waypoint(function(){
        var i = 1,
        delay = [];
        $(this).find('.project-thumb').each(function(i){
            i++;
            var elem = $(this);
            delay[i] = setTimeout(function(){
                elem.addClass('in');
            },200*i);
        })
    },{offset:'70%'});

    $('.iphones-wrapper.scrollimation').waypoint(function(){
        $(this).find('.iphone-landscape-frame').addClass('in');
    },{offset:'60%'});
```

and this  CSS associate with it

```
.scrollimation.fade-up{
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100px);
    transform:translateY(100px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .4s ease-out,opacity .4s ease-in;
    transition: transform .4s ease-out,opacity .4s ease-in-out;
}

.scrollimation.fade-up.in{
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform:translateY(0px);
}
```

on a HTML page it does work once I get it into a .net page I won't 
Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the output source HTML of the entire page so we spot any issues (not the source page). It may simply be down to the order/placement of scripts in the page.

Comment: I coludn't understand output but, most html, .net conflicts about jquery versions or meta tags to force older versions.

Comment: everything in the output code is there, but the problem is that the divs set to opacity=0 to strart the animation. That means the animation got stuck with the initial opacity of  0 and did not transition to opacity 1 in the scrollimation.fade-up.in class.  On a regular html in works fine

Answer (score 1):

modernizer was causing the issue. Just move  /js/libs/modernizr.min.js to the js directory with all the other files an problem solved.